# richembed fields may not be empty error -- How would I fix this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I keep getting an error on my console saying that RichEmbed fields may not be empty. When I have defined values for each field... Here's the code:

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}suggest`) {
  // USAGE:
  // /suggest this is the suggestion

  const suggestion = args.join(' ').slice(22);

  const suggestEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setDescription('~~-------~~**__NEW SUGGESTION!__**~~-------~~')
      .setColor('#ff0000')
      .addField('Suggestion By', `${message.author} (${message.author.id})`)
      .addField('Channel', message.channel)
      .addField('Time', message.createdAt)
      .addField('Suggestion', suggestion)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('Use /invite to invite me to your server!');

  const suggestchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, 'suggestions');
  if (!suggestchannel) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find suggestions channel. Please **create one for this command to work!**");


  message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
  suggestchannel.send({ embed: suggestEmbed });
}
```

And here's the error:

```
(node:616) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: RichEmbed field values may not be empty.
    at RichEmbed.addField
```

I would appreciate some help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that `args[1]` is provided. Then, assuming the first string in `args` is the command, change the declaration of `suggestion` to...

```js
const suggestion = args.slice(1).join(' ');
```

**Edit:** Also change the line for the suggestion field to...

```js
.addField('Suggestion', suggestion.length <= 1024 ? suggestion : suggestion.slice(0, 1020) + '...')
```

That will prevent any errors resulting in `suggestion` being too long for an embed field.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a whole Object in a RichEmbed as a value. You're trying to enter the **channel Object** as RichEmbed value which is not allowed.

I suppose you want to add the `channel.name` to this RichEmbed field. I changed the code so it shows the name of the channel.

**Here is the corrected code:**

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}suggest`) {
    // USAGE:
    // /suggest this is the suggestion

    const suggestion = args.join(' ').slice(22);

    const suggestEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription('~~-------~~**__NEW SUGGESTION!__**~~-------~~')
        .setColor('#ff0000')
        .addField('Suggestion By', `${message.author} (${message.author.id})`)
        .addField('Channel', message.channel.name)
        .addField('Time', message.createdAt)
        .addField('Suggestion', suggestion)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('Use /invite to invite me to your server!');

    const suggestchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, 'suggestions');
    if (!suggestchannel) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find suggestions channel. Please **create one for this command to work!**");


    message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
    suggestchannel.send({ embed: suggestEmbed });
  }
```

Comment: `
        `.addField('Suggestion', suggestion)`

Comment: Then `suggestion` is an empty string

Comment: but i defined it i did /suggest test

Comment: I can‘t help you if I don‘t know how you defined `args`

Comment: hmmmm i justdid it by the cmd

Comment: `/suggest <suggestion>`

Comment: but you use `args`, what's the definition of `args`

Comment: Just a suggestion, but maybe it would be better if you joined the [discord.js](https://discord.gg/bRCvFy9) guild and field some of these questions there. I'm only basing this on the last 3 questions you've raised. Might be easier to get quick feedback in the community designed for the library you're using.

Comment: I guess you should do: `suggestion = args.join(' ');` as the `.slice(22)` is the "cheap and dumb" way of cutting away a mention.

Comment: Lmao so true. Now I've changed the way I utilise message#mentions Thanks :D